# long delay in (win)rar before adding files

Tags: linux, files, performance, rar

This is running 64-bit rar on an aws ami linux ec2 instance (4 cpu cores, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90GHz, 8gb RAM).

I have a folder with 8568 files. When I create a rar file and add all the files to it, it takes about 3 minutes before it begins processing adding the files. Is this normal? Do you know what the reason for the delay might be (analyzing the files?)? The command I'm using:

```
/usr/local/bin/rar a -r -iddpq -ierr /path/to/compress/myfile.rar /path/to/compress/*.log
```

Each file is only about 980 bytes.

Comment: `rar` is a Windows program ported to UNIX. As such, it has a Windows mindset towards expanding globs on the command line, and believes the program is responsible for the expansion, not the shell. So whenever you run `rar` in a directory with 55k files in subdirectories `rar` will dutifully find and catalog them all before doing what you told it to.  This is likely to be the slowdown you're seeing.  Workaround: always run `rar` in (mostly) empty directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running a reduced-scope test, I see that the `rar` binary is calling `stat` on each file 7 times before finally opening the file to read the contents. I would have chased down the behavior in the source code, but it's not available (in debian, at least).

```
$ strace -o rar.strace rar a -r -iddpq -ierr path/to/compress/myfile.rar path/to/compress/*.log
...
$ grep /5.log rar.strace
execve("/usr/bin/rar", ["rar", "a", "-r", "-iddpq", "-ierr", "path/to/compress/myfile.rar", "path/to/compress/1.log", "path/to/compress/2.log", "path/to/compress/3.log", "path/to/compress/4.log", "path/to/compress/5.log"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
stat64("path/to/compress/5.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=980, ...}) = 0
stat64("path/to/compress/5.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=980, ...}) = 0
stat64("path/to/compress/5.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=980, ...}) = 0
stat64("path/to/compress/5.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=980, ...}) = 0
stat64("path/to/compress/5.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=980, ...}) = 0
stat64("path/to/compress/5.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=980, ...}) = 0
stat64("path/to/compress/5.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=980, ...}) = 0
open("path/to/compress/5.log", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 5
```

Comment: `rar` is a commercial program, the source is not available.

Comment: It'd be nice to see timing data on those calls.  You can add `-T` and some variation of `-t`, `-tt`, and `-ttt` to the `strace` arguments to get the time spend in the system calls along with timestamps.on each call `strace()` emits output for.  Even that many `stat` calls on a file shouldn't be *that* slow compared to doing actual IO on the file - the inode data should be cached and readily available to the kernel after the first call.  Sure that many `stat` calls are a waste, but I'd think there has to be something more fundamentally wrong with how `rar` is going about its business.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - pasted into http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56467/further-strace-detail-for-qlong-delay-in-winrar-before-adding-files

Comment: @JeffSchaller  Ouch.  It looks like that thing also calls `stat()` on `/etc/localtime` about 5 times for every other system call it makes. Seems to be a case of, "Poorly-implemented software runs poorly."  But note that the first time `stat()` is called on a file, it's often an order of magnitude slower than later calls to `stat()` on that same file.